# An automated process, daily job to save specific SQL Server tables from a specific database into Excel file format

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and my requirement is to develop an automated process to run on a daily basis in order to save some SQL Server tables from a specific database into Excel file on local system.

I have the following on my machine:

- SSIS Business Intelligence
- Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version 12.0.2430.0
- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools 12.0.61021.0
- Visual Studio Professional 2013
- SQL Server 2012 Express edition (free edition doesn’t have Import/Export SSIS package wizard)

I have created a SSIS package under SSBI Integration Services using following two approaches

**Approach 1:** Using File System Task and Data Flow Task
  (Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlWlQyIt86g&pbjreload=10)

**Approach 2:** Using Script task from control flow
  (Source: http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/03/how-to-export-sql-server-tables-from.html)

SSIS package reads the SQL Server tables and saves output file as Excel file in local folder path. Package is working fine on local Visual Studio. However, I'm having problem when I tried to automate the process by executing the SSIS package either from the SQL Server job agent or from the command prompt to make a bat file.

**From the SQL Server job agent**: when I load the SSIS package in SQL Server job agent steps from local source, I'm getting

> 0xC0010014** exception related to `LoadFromXML` fails please refer the attached file.

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this exception is this due to me using a free SQL Server version? I couldn’t find solution for this.

[image]

**From the command prompt**: I found `dtexec` in the following paths, latest modified date is with the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe`

[image]

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn
```

I have executed the following command

**With DTS path 120:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\dtexec.exe" /File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\DataBackupExcel.dtsx"
```

results in:

> Exception: Code: 0xC000F427
>   Source: File System Task
>   Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install File System Task of Integration Services or higher.

**With DTS path 110:**

> Code: 0xC001700A
>   Source: DataBackupExcel
>   Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.
>
> Code: 0xC0016020
>   Source: DataBackupExcel
>   Description: Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A; "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.".
>
> Code: 0xC0010018
>   Source: DataBackupExcel
>   Description: Error loading value "8" from node "DTS:Property".
>
> Could not load package "C:\Users\username\Desktop\ DataBackupExcel.dtsx" because of error 0xC0010014.
>
> Description: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
>   Source: DataBackupExcel

Initially I thought it's doable task, but now I'm stuck at one point and I'm not able to go further. Am I missing anything or any version mismatch couldn't able to figure out? Please don't consider this post as duplicate, I have tried different approaches mentioned in SO and other sources but none of them worked. Like (updating the SSIS from VS updates, file path changes and executing command on administrator mode etc)

Comment: Is this a 1 to 1 export? Meaning, you are exporting 1 table to 1 Excel file? Is the Excel file formatted specifically, or just dump the table into Excel?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2014, have you considered deploying your packages using SSISDB  and using SQL Server agent instead? No need for DTExec then.

Comment: @ WEI_DBA , at beginning, I want to focus on 1 table to 1 Excel. I have Services db table and exporting it into excel Services sheet. Using File System Task and Data Flow Task mentioned in my post approach 1. what do you mean by Excel file special formatting ?

Comment: @ Larnu we are using MS SQL Server 2012. Unfortunately I can't change it for now. If I didn't find solution with SQL Server 2012, I will request my team to upgrade to 2014.

Comment: You need a Standard or higher level version of SQL Server. Express doesn't support SSIS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @digital.aaron, thanks for the reference and unfortunately we can't upgrade now. that's why I'm trying alternatives like creating a bat file to execute SSIS from command prompt.

Comment: @priya777 there is no work around that will allow you to run SSIS without having the packages on a Standard or higher version of SQL Server.   What you can do is write a console app that will do what you were trying to do in SSIS.

Comment: @ Tab Alleman can we run console app on daily basis automatically ?I never tried this I will look around. Any references would be helpful. please do share. thanks.

Comment: Yes a console app can be scheduled to run automatically.   I don't have any references handy.

Comment: SQl Server 2012 also supports SSISDB. it was introduced with that version. Also, when tagging, don't put a space between the name and @. It won't mention the user otherwise (and they won't know you commented back). @Larnu is correct, not @ Larnu.